# How do I store duplicate email addresses?

Tags: parse-platform

Using parse.com's API, how do I store multiple email addresses?

Currently if two users set the same email address I get the following error:

> Error: the email address has already been taken

Is it possible to allow duplicate values? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The email field on ParseUser is special and is validated against other email addresses for uniqueness.  However, you can always store email addresses in a custom field e.g. `[[PFUser current] setObject:@"someDuplicate@email.com" forKey:@"contactEmail"]`, which won't be validated, allowing you to have duplicates.

Comment: Doing this won't allow for users to use the Forgot password feature correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the parse.com API is returning this error then it's a restriction on their side, in which case the answer is: you can't.  If this is an error your own database is returning, then you need to offer more information as to why.

Comment: it's on parse.com's side. Is there no way to customize the tables I use?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I'm afraid that you're at the mercy of someone elses' database design.